# Convert an asynchronous function to a synchronous function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I use a certain Node.js class for text categorization. In its simplest form, it looks like this:

```
function TextCategorizer(preprocessors) {
      ...
}
```

"preprocessors" is an array of functions of the form:

```
function(text) {
    return "<modified text>"
}
```

They can be used, for example, to remove punctuations, convert to lower case, etc.

I can use the TextCategorizer like this:

```
var cat = newTextCategorizer(preprocessors);
cat.train(text1,class1);
cat.train(text2,class2);
...
console.log(cat.classify(text3,class3);
```

The preprocessors are called in order for every training text and classified text.

Now, I need to add a new preprocessor function - a spelling correcter. The best spelling corrected I found works asynchronously (through a web-service), so, the function looks like this:

```
correctSpelling(text, callback) {
     ... 
     callback(corrected_version_of_text);
}
```

i.e. it does not return a value, but rather calls a callback function with the value.

My question is: how can I use the correctSpelling function, as one of the preprocessors in the preprocessors array I send to TextCategorizer?

Comment: Why not use it asynchronously? Async is the node mantra.

Comment: As a standalone function, of course I can use it asynchronously. But as I explained in the question, I want to use it as an input to another module, which expects a synchronous function.

Comment: Put your preproccessors in a closure with the async call.  Then define your callback in this closure, so the callback function has access to the preprocessor array.

Comment: @ChrisCM   
"Put your preproccessors in a closure with the async call" - what does it mean? How do I do this?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I believe ChrisCM means what I posted in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If you want to put a bunch of tasks in a certain order, you could you the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) framework (npm install async). There is a specific feature for synchronizing async functions called "series".</strike>

It sounds like you are having a problem using both sync and async functions. In that case, I think you should wrap all sync functions in an async function like so

```
function asyncFunc(args, callback){
    process.nextTick(function() {
        callback(syncFunc(args));
    });
}
```

Then you should chain them together using the `async` module.

It looks like this may make an asynchronous function synchronous.

[waitfor on github](https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: "series" takes an array of asynchronous functions, calls them in order, and returns the results to another callback. But, I still don't see how I can use it to send an asynchronous function to a class that expects a synchronous function...

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Can you include a bit more code? I don't see why you can pass a synchronous callback to your function asynchronously.

Comment: What access do you have to the TextCategorizer? If you can get to the source code, I believe you could instrument an event-based solution (which I'll describe based on how you answer.)

Comment: @RobRaisch I have access to the TextCategorizer source code. However, I highly prefer to leave it as it is, because most of the inputs are simple synchronous functions (i.e. replace some regular expressions, etc.). There is only a single function that is asynchronous, and I wouldn't want to change everything just fot a single function. Unless there is no other way...

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I've updated my answer. I still suggest using the async module, and wrapping the sync functions in async functions.

Comment: @JoshC, I think your answer does the exact opposite of what is needed. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the question is not how to make the a sync function appear async, but rather, given a pipeline of existing sync functions, how would one add an asynchronous function so it can be run synchronously.

Comment: @RobRaisch yes, but I'm suggesting to convert everything to async calls. I think trying to make this synchronous is the wrong approach. Instead, make everything async, and then chain in series.

Comment: @JoshC, Oh I agree that would be the best approach but it appears that the pipeline that calls the existing preprocessors expects synchronous calls and cannot be modified. Further, it must be called twice, once when building the classifiers and again when attempting to classify a new document. If this is correct, asynchronizing the preprocessors wouldn't work.

Comment: @RobRaisch Maybe I missed something, but he should be able convert to async calls if he owns the pipeline code, no?

Comment: @JoshC, while he may own the steps in the pipeline, the invocation of the pipeline is opaque. The only other option, as I indicate below, would seem to be to preprocess documents before the TextCategorizer gets to see them, which would mean providing his own preprocessing pipeline.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36057/discussion-between-josh-c-and-rob-raisch)

Comment: Thank you. It is unfortunate that what I want to do is impossible, but, it is good to know that it is impossible :)

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi I believe there is a way to do what you want. See the update to my post.

Answer (score 1):

If my comment above regarding my understanding of your problem is correct, I don't believe there is a way of un-asynchronizing an async call the way you want, without modifying the source of the TextCategorizer, which you'd indicated wouldn't be optimal.

My only other thought is to run your documents through the existing list of preprocessors before calling train() and classify() which would allow you to follow JoshC's advice.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [**Fibers**](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) if you really want to do it.

```
var Future = require('fibers/future'), wait = Future.wait;
var fs = require('fs');

// This wraps existing functions assuming the last argument of the passed
// function is a callback. The new functions created immediately return a
// future and the future will resolve when the callback is called (which
// happens behind the scenes).
var readdir = Future.wrap(fs.readdir);
var stat = Future.wrap(fs.stat);

Fiber(function() {
    // Get a list of files in the directory
    var fileNames = readdir('.').wait();
    console.log('Found '+ fileNames.length+ ' files');

    // Stat each file
    var stats = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < fileNames.length; ++ii) {
        stats.push(stat(fileNames[ii]));
    }
    wait(stats);

    // Print file size
    for (var ii = 0; ii < fileNames.length; ++ii) {
        console.log(fileNames[ii]+ ': '+ stats[ii].get().size);
    }
}).run();
```

See **FUTURES** (https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers#futures)