# What is the big deal about asynchronous Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have just started reading more about what asynchronous programming is all about and would ask if my reasoning below is correct and if it is not what am i misunderstanding?

My understanding is that asynchronous programming is mostly relevant when talking about I/O, this is because the execution of I/O events are handled by some other execution environment for example the operation system, or database. 
However I could also run two instances of Node.js for example one instance that needs to be highly responsive on which I instantly pass over execution of long running Javascript processes to another Node.js instance where the longer running processes can lock the singel thread and only send back the callback telling the responsive server that the execution was ok? The most common way to create an external execution environment in which to run asynchronous javascript is to start WebWorkers to avoid blocking the single three?
It is also possible to write asynchronous code that has no positive effect, for example if all my asynchronous code is executed on a singel Node.js instance and not passed away to some other execution environment. This would give me no positive effect and only lead to a much more complicated program logic, all my code would still need to be executed in the same environment?

So in conclusion, asynchronous programming is all about avoiding executing anything in the singel thread, you only want to pass along the actual execution to some other process?

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work with multiple threads, so I'm confused at what you're asking here

Comment: Asynchronous programming is not just relevant for I/O. It is common in other places as well.

Comment: [Try reading this answer about asynchronousy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919075)

Comment: I think the OP is confusing asynchronous threads with callbacks

Comment: @IngoBürk I find that asynchronous programming is *all* about I/O, but in a more general sense - some *input* event/signal, including a timer expiring, triggers the continuation of execution.

Comment: @user2864740 A non-I/O-related example would be requests from external systems which take some time to process (e.g. because you have to make requests to other systems or wait for requests from several systems to process this request). Instead of replying synchronously, which would be blocking for the entire time and would likely lead to timeouts, you have an asychronous protocol to separare request and response.

Comment: @IngoBürk The continued execution of delayed code under the asynchronous programming model is *always* in reaction to *input* signals/triggers. It is a general *input* driven model: a SQL transaction completing, a line of a file being read from disk, a timer firing after some delay, completion of a computation on a distributed network node or a background worker ..

Comment: @user2864740 I misunderstood you at first. I get now what you're saying, although I'm not sure it's *always* true. Say I process requests, but only send responses through a cronjob that runs once a day. Where is the input signal? "The code is being executed" is not an input signal that differs from synchronous code, it's an inherent property of running software.

Comment: @IngoBürk The signal would be the result of the timer expiring according to the cron rules which results in the execution of the appropriate programs. Cron itself need not follow the asynchronous model to implement the behavior, just as the underlying JavaScript implementation does not, but the programs it ran could be viewed as being run asynchronously - although it seems a bit tenuous to argue for such because of no implicitly maintained (or standard framework to maintain) state between the different tasks.

Comment: @user2864740 But with that reasoning every code will run when it gets an input signal (e.g. being called). Saying asynchronous behavior is always continued by some sort of "trigger" is completely correct, it's just that the same goes for synchronous behavior: every code runs only if it is triggered to be executed.

Comment: @IngoBürk Ah, yes. I guess it is a bit vague when viewed that way - and why the argument for cron programs being asynchronous is tenuous. An asynchronous programming model relies on the ability to queue "work to be done later in response to an input/event", such that queuing the tasks does not stop the current execution. (Such a queue need not be dynamic, although it most certainly is in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous programming is *especially* but not only useful for I/O.

The idea is that I/O reads and writes can take a long time, and it's not always necessary to wait for them. You can continue executing code while you wait. For instance, you can load a file, execute a query and do a REST request to another service. Your node application can start all these in the same time, asynchronously, and then wait until each of them is finished.

In PHP for instance, this is very hard to accomplish, and you will waste time waiting until the file is loaded, waste more time until the query is executed, and then wait even more for the REST request, because you cannot start them at the same time.

So this is a big advantage, although it's also a bit theoretical. In practise, you'll find quite often that you need the output of one request/query/file as the input for the next.

Node is not single threaded per se (actually, I cincerely hope it is not). But you won't have to implement multi-threading yourself. Also, it *could* be multithreaded although it doesn't have to be. Even in a single threaded and/or single-core environment it can still be faster, because you can actually pause executing of one task until the I/O that is part of it is finished. Like I said, in PHP your script cannot do anything else while it waits for a response of the database, while in Node you can.

Comment: I think the core thing I don't understand is when people say "For instance, you can load a file, execute a query and do a REST request to another service." Well sure I can but all these operation has to actually be executed somewhere, even if it is I/O it will use the CPU, is it so that node spawns some sort of light weight threads to handle the execution or is it just calling some OS pacific code to handle the actual execution?

Comment: I'm not fully aware of all implementation details of Node, but it will use threads if necessary. But it also works with messages when possible. It can receive messages from the OS when a certain event happens, for instance when a timer goes off. Some operations (like file I/O) cannot do this, and will have to be wrapped in threads. The I/O operation itself doesn't cost much CPU. If you wait for a REST service, then that's all your CPU does: waiting. While it waits, it can do other things. Switching between threads is fast, and a CPU can even execute code while waiting for a hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

The big deal about asynchronous Javascript is that you can write an asynchronous program without thinking in terms of low level constructs like threads. In Javascript you can handle complex concurrency logic by simply chaining together your program's execution using mechanisms like callbacks and events.

The big deal about asynchronous programming in general is that you can handle things that may take a significant amount of time to execute like opening a file, downloading an image or calculating Pi without blocking other processes from doing their jobs.

The secret to concurrency in Javascript is the ["event loop"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop) which allows asynchronous behavior in a single threaded environment.